# Add new div to image elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Im trying to add a new div element to all images. I need the new div text to display on the bottom right of all images.

What Im trying:

```
var links = document.images;
for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
    var div_link = document.createElement("div");
    div_link.style.position = "relative";
    div_link.style.bottom = "10px";
    div_link.style.left = "10px";
    div_link.innerHTML = "56259";
    console.log(links[i]);
    links[i].appendChild(div_link);   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images can not have child elements, so appending to them is not going to work. You can insert the div before the image.

```
links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(links[i], div_link);
```

Comment: Or, wrap img e.g. using jQuery: `$("img").wrap("<div></div>");`.

Comment: You can do something like the following if you want the div inserted *after* the image: links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(div_link, links[i].nextSibling);

Comment: @mg007, where in the world did jQuery get included here?

Comment: @epascarello I was suggesting an alternative which better maintains document structure instead of a div sticking above the img. jQuery was used as an example, you could translate that to js if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a figure element:

```
<figure>
  <img src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Wrap the images with JQuery like this:

```
$('img').wrap('<figure />');
$('figure').append('<figcaption>Nice image!</figcaption>');
```

Comment: And where is the jQuery tag? ;)